# C++ Accessing a variable that has been declared/ defined in one source file from another source file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a variable that I am trying to use in a C++ source file called `Spiral.cpp`. The variable has been declared in a header file using the following code:

```
struct DataMessage{
    ...
    ::CORBA::Double radius;
    ...
};
```

inside:

```
namespace STEERDataIDL{
    ...
}
```

It has then been given a value in another source file called `Module.cpp`, using the following line:

```
radius = Interface.spiralRadius;
```

inside `case STEERDataIDL::SpiralPattern:`

of the function:

```
void Module::FormList(void){
    ...
    switch (this->InterCDNUSteerData.SteerMode)
{
          ....
      }
}
```

As the line above would suggest, the value given to the variable here has been taken from user input on a GUI.

As mentioned, I am then trying to use this variable in a function in my `Spiral.cpp` source file:

```
void Module::FormList(); /*This is the function in which `radius` was given its value */
if(abs(someDistance) < (Data.radius + x)){
    // Do XYZ
}
```

However, I'm getting a few compile errors which I don't understand:

> error 'module' is not a class or namespace name      (on the `void Module::` line)
>
> > 'x' undeclared identifier
> >
> > > left of '.radius' must have class/ struct/ union, type is "unkown type"

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? What do I need to do to fix these compile errors?

Comment: *What do I need to do to fix these compile errors?* First, you should post a complete example which would produce errors you are talking about.

Comment: `#include` the header where the variable/class is declared.

Comment: I have included the header where the variable is declared. There is far too much code to post a complete example, which is why I have just posted the sections of code referenced in the compile errors, and explained the structure of the code with regards to which variables are declared/ used in which source files.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here.

1. You define the variable TYPE `(struct DataMessage....)` in the header file but don't declare the variable itself
2. The variable cannot be defined in the header file, only declared for external reference **outside of the namespace**.
   `extern struct STEERDataIDL::DataMessage Data;`
3. in Module.cpp you don't seem to reference a variable named "Data" of type struct DataMessage anywhere even though you attempt to access it in Spiral.cpp
   `struct STEERDataIDL::DataMessage Data;`
4. You're missing a closing parenthesis in Spiral.cpp

The important thing is that all `extern`s are declared at file scope.  technically, you can put the `extern struct STEERDataIDL::DataMessage Data;` immediately before the line where you use the variable, provided it can resolve the scope properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. The struct defined in the header contains about 80 variables of different types, which are used elsewhere in the program, and aren't causing any issues... and surely I am declaring the variable inside the struct with the line `::CORBA::Double radius;`? 2. I tried using `extern struct DataMessage Data;` but got a compile error that said "local classes cannot be used to declare 'extern' variables... 3. In Module.cpp, I have the line: `radius = Data.radius;`, although maybe I need to declare this with the line `extern struct DataMessage Data;` first? 4. Copy error

Comment: You didn't provide enough information in the original question.  You did not indicate the scope of any of your declarations or definitions which is extremely important.  Are you declaring/defining things in file scope? function scope? class scope? namespace scope?

Comment: Apologies, I have added some more information about where the functions & variables are defined/ declared- hopefully this will give you enough information?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the header file in which Data is declared, for that matter, the declaration of Data would look something like this:

```
//globals.h
#include "DataMessage.h"
extern DataMessage Data;  //to indicate that Data will be created in a different cpp file and visible to other cpp files
```

You should then have Data created in a cpp file that includes the header file in which the variable Data was declared, which may look like this:

```
//globals.cpp
#include "globals.h"
DataMessage Data;
```

now in Module.cpp you probably have something like this:

```
#include "globals.h"
...
void Module::FormList() {
  Data.radius = Interface.spiralRadius;  //notice how radius is accessible only through the Data variable
}
```

and in Spiral.cpp you should have something like this:

```
#include "globals.h"
...
void Foo() {
  if(abs(someDistance) < (Data.radius + x)) {  //Data.radius is the same one across all files
    // Do XYZ
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've given your first point a go- but I get differing compile errors for that depending on how I do it. If I do: `extern DataMessage Data;`, I get `syntax error: missing ';' before 'Data'`... If I do `extern struct DataMessage Data;`, I get `local classes cannot be used to declare 'extern' variables`...